# Concurrent AWS S3 copying of images listed in MySQL

Tags: performance, mysql, concurrency, go, amazon-web-services

I created the following one off script and it did the task quite well (1000s of requests / second with low CPU usage - outperformed the previous python script in every aspect). But I am wondering if there are more "gophonic" ways to accomplish this in Golang? (the word for pythonic in Go? :p )  The code was gofmt'd and golint'd.

The result set is variable but in the range between 100k and 20M rows (as such so many copy requests to AWS has to be done).

After some helpful comments I already edited the code once to rename the concurrency flag to reflect the intend of the current (original) implementation better (numberChannels -> numberGoRoutinesForCopy).

My main concern for this review is to have optimal efficiency with large number of concurrent invocations of `copyKey` independent of where the data came from, resp. what exactly the copying does.

```
import (
    "flag"
    "log"
    "os"

    "database/sql"
    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"

    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/session"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/s3"
)

var (
    from = flag.String(
        "from", "2011-01-01 00:00:00",
        "From Date.",
    )
    to = flag.String(
        "to", "2011-12-31 23:59:59",
        "To Date.",
    )
    region = flag.String(
        "aws.region", "us-east-1",
        "AWS region.",
    )
    numberGoRoutinesForCopy = flag.Int(
       "concurrency", 250,
       "Concurrent Requests.",
    )

    sizes = [11]string{
        "catalog",
        "catalog-m",
        "cart",
        "product",
        "product-m",
        "gallery",
        "zoom",
        "related",
        "list",
        "feed",
        "progressproduct",
    }
)    

type imageMetaData struct {
    ID    string
    Sku   string
    Image string
    Size  string
}

func main() {
    log.SetOutput(os.Stdout)
    flag.Parse()
    done := make(chan bool)

    sess := session.Must(session.NewSession())

    svc := s3.New(sess, aws.NewConfig().WithRegion(*region))

    ch := make(chan imageMetaData)
    go getData(*from, *to, ch)

    log.Println(*numberGoRoutinesForCopy)
    for i := 0; i < *numberGoRoutinesForCopy; i++ {
        go func(messages <-chan imageMetaData) {
            for data := range messages {
                copyKey(data, svc)
            }
            close(done)
        }(ch)
    }

    <-done
    log.Println("done")
}


func getData(from string, to string, ch chan imageMetaData) {

    var (
        id    string
        sku   string
        image string
    )

    db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "database_conn")
    db.SetMaxIdleConns(0)
    if err != nil {
        // we won't stop on error
        log.Println(err.Error())
    }
    defer db.Close()

    rows, err := db.Query("SELECT some_big_sql_left_out_for_brevity")
    if err != nil {
        // we won't stop on error
        log.Println(err)
    }
    defer rows.Close()

    for rows.Next() {
        err := rows.Scan(&id, &sku, &image)
        if err != nil {
            // we won't stop on error
            log.Println(err)
        }

        for _, size := range sizes {
            ch <- imageMetaData{
                Id:    id,
                Sku:   sku,
                Image: image,
                Size:  size,
            }
        }
    }

    close(ch)
}    

func copyKey(ImageData imageMetaData, svc *s3.S3) {

    var keyName = getKeyName(ImageData)
    params := &s3.CopyObjectInput{
        Bucket:     aws.String("some_bucket"),
        CopySource: aws.String("some_other_bucket/" + keyName),
        Key:        aws.String(keyName),
    }

    _, err := svc.CopyObject(params)

    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }

    log.Println(keyName + " copied")
}

func getKeyName(ImageData imageMetaData) string {
    runes := []rune(ImageData.Id)
    for i, j := 0, len(runes)-1; i < j; i, j = i+1, j-1 {
        runes[i], runes[j] = runes[j], runes[i]
    }
    return string(runes) + "/" + ImageData.Image + "-" + ImageData.Size + ".jpg"
}
```

Comment: There's not much concurrency in here at all, and the `numberChannels` variable looks useless. You have 3 active routines only, one of them is mostly just waiting on `done`. your code is missing the `flag` handling and variables, and also the `copyKey` function (and that function will have a big impact on the need for concurrency depending on what that does).

Comment: @rolfl I added the rest of the code, in fact I mean to get high throughput - so I start `numberChannels` of goroutines to process the data (requests to s3)

Comment: Just a little question: why won't you stop on error? Regarding performance, I don't know how exactly channels in Go work, but _maybe_ it would be more efficient to create one channel per `copyKey` goroutine and alternately send data into these channels in `getData`.

Comment: @kyrill the first 2 times ignoring the error on db connection problems really doesn't make sense (it was late :-) ) - the last time I wanted to ignore the error when `Scan` a row into variables, because I don't care if a single row failed (with about 10M rows) - I needed to migrate the 2 S3 buckets in 2 different locations as fast as possible (with minor errors to analyze later).

IIRC I had one version where I tried to get one goroutine per row but this effectively too much (even when I lowered the result set to 100k) - but maybe I missed something here.

Comment: Not one goroutine per row, but one channel per goroutine. As rolfl pointed out, your `numberChannels` variable is useless, because you always create only one channel.

Comment: @kyrill @rolfl  Oh, yes I just realized that the name`numberChannels`doesn't make sense at all - `numberGoRoutinesForCopy` would match better for how it is implemented currently I think. A channel per goroutine would mean I would need to parametrize the `getData` function to return equal chunks for each channel? (I did this in the python version to split onto multiprocess / threads)

Comment: No, you don't have to send exactly the same number of `imageMetaData` into each channel, just roughly the same. Also, I don't think you will "parametrize" `getData` any further, just instead of passing a single channel, you will pass an array (or slice) of channels.

Comment: @kyrill ic, somehow my performance decreased when I tried this (for now I just changed the variable name)

Comment: OK then. Maybe try with more goroutines, or less channels per goroutine (eg. 1000 goroutines with 50 channels, etc). But it's possibly most efficient with just one channel.

Comment: How do you know, for sure, that by the time `close(ch)` is called, the processing routine has done all it needed to do? Use `sync.WaitGroup` for things like that. Rule of thumb is also: close a channel in the routine that creates it. What you're doing with `done` is not considered best practices. Just push a value onto a non-buffered channel: reads and writes block in that case